# Why do I get a NameError in my class that stores animals?

Tags: python

I'm supposed to make a class that stores animals, and then a method that returns the animals name and number in a list.

```
class Animal:
    """
    A class for storing animals
    
    class attributes:
        animals: (list) to store all animals
    instance attributes:
        name:  (str) to store animal name
        number: (int) to store animal order number (starting with 1)
          
    class methods:
        __str__: string representation of animal, e.g. "1. Dog"
        
    static methods:
        zoo: returns string representation of all animals in orderd lies, e.g. 
           '''\
           1. Dog
           2. Cat'''
    """

    animals = []
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        
    def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.number}. {self.name}'
    
    # The test to pass:

    Animal.animals.clear()

    dog = Animal('dog')
    assert dog.name == 'dog', error_message(dog.name, 'dog')
    assert dog.number == 1, error_message(dog.number, 1)
    assert str(dog) == '1. Dog', error_message(str(dog), '1. Dog')

    cat = Animal('cat')
    assert cat.name == 'cat', error_message(cat.name, 'cat')
    assert cat.number == 2, error_message(cat.number, 2)
    assert str(cat) == '2. Cat', error_message(str(cat), '2. Cat')
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[254], line 3
  1 Animal.animals.clear()
----> 3 dog = Animal('dog')
  4 assert dog.name == 'dog', error_message(dog.name, 'dog')
  5 assert dog.number == 1, error_message(dog.number, 1)

Cell In[253], line 27, in Animal.__init__(self, name)
 25 def __init__(self, name):
 26     self.name = name
---> 27     self.number = number

NameError: name 'number' is not defined
```

What does this mean? How can I fix it?

Comment: We answer specific questions here, not general pleas for help. Your plea for help is better directed to a tutor or friendly classmate or something like that.

Comment: You're missing the `number` parameter to `__init__()`: `def __init__(self, name, number):`

Comment: @Bamar - I added the missing `"""` ***before*** I saw your comment

Comment: Your "*I barely understand what I'm doing*" tells us that you posted your question before you were ready to present your problem.

Comment: @Barmar According to the test, `Animal()` only takes one argument: `dog = Animal('dog')`. This means that the `number` field needs to be assigned in another way.

Comment: `number` should be a class attribute. Every time you create a new animal, increment it and assign that to `self.attribute`.

Comment: @PM 77-1 I'm having a hard time, there's no need to be unfriendly. If you don't have any help to give then don't bother comment?

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that you don't have a variable named `number`. You need a way to count how many animals have been created so far and assign a "number" to the next animal based on that count.